# Selenium Remote Web Driver: How do I determine which IEDriverServer.exe (32-bit or 64-bit) is being used?

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium via its Python bindings on one side, and via the Selenium standalone server on the other side.  Here is the server command line I am using:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe
```

The IEDriverServer.exe comes in two flavors:  32-bit and 64-bit.  There is a well-known bug in which using the 64-bit version causes tests to execute incredibly slowly.  For example, when sending text to an edit box, it takes 4 or 5 seconds for each character sent.  The solution is to use the 32-bit driver, even on 64-bit Windows.

When I run with the 32-bit version, I see this in the server output when I create an IE browser instance:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to determine which version is running from the client side.  It doesn't get returned in the capabilities, as the IE version does.

How can I determine which driver is running from the client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, we have that option to check using Selenium. What can be done is using the Browser object, we can pick the Title and map it with the process running on the machine.
I have written the C# code to print the Browser path (EXE), by which we can determine whether the Browser is of 32-bit or 64-bit.

```
public static void PrintBrowserDetails()
    {
        string procName = "iexplore";

        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process proc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(procName))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                if (proc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(Util.Browser.Title))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection prm = proc.Modules;
                    foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule pm in prm)
                    {
                        if (pm.ModuleName.Contains("IEXPLORE.EXE"))
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fi = pm.FileVersionInfo;
                            Console.WriteLine(fi.FileName); // Output: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
                            Console.WriteLine(fi.FileVersion); // Output: 8.0.7601.17514
                            Console.WriteLine(fi.FileDescription); // Internet Explorer.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Util.Browser -> Selenium Browser object
```

Hope this might help you.